# Can't find any examples of google.maps.places.PlacesService() and getting errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Can't find any examples of google.maps.places.PlacesServices() that searches from an input field with component restrictions, just like autocomplete. [Google site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery) only has reference material, no examples

I have this below but getting an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findPlaceFromQuery' of null

```js
findLocationFromPlaces() {
    this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.cityInput);

    const request = {
      query: 'San Francisco',
      fields: ['photos', 'formatted_address', 'name', 'rating', 'opening_hours', 'geometry']
    };

    this.placesService.findPlaceFromQuery(request
      // {
      //   types: ['(cities)']
      //   // componentRestrictions: { country: this.countrySelected },
      //   // types: ['geocode']  // 'establishment' / 'address' / 'geocode'
      // }
    ,
    (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        
      }
      else {
          
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

My "this.cityInput" is

```js
@ViewChild('city') cityInput: HTMLDivElement;
```

```html
<input appGooglePlaces id="city" (onSelect)="setAddress($event)" (keydown.Tab)="onTabAway($event)" (focusout)="focusOutFunction($event)" (input)="onLocationChange($event)" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': registerForm.get('city').errors && registerForm.get('city').touched}"
  formControlName="city" class="form-control google-place-input" [placeholder]="placeholder">
```

Answer (score 4):

The Places service is used for place searches. It cannot behave like the Autocomplete service does. Furthermore, you cannot pass componentRestrictions to findPlaceFromQuery(). This method takes 3 parameters only: query, fields and the optional locationBias (which biases but does not restrict the area to search).

The documentation for Find Place from Query can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query), and [here's a working example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search).

If you also wish to implement Autocomplete functionality and e.g. restrict results to a specific country, please use the actual [Autocomplete service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete).

**Edit for mapless options:**

1. Find place from query

   ```
   function findLocationFromPlaces() {
       let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("map")); // i.e. <div id="map"></div>

       const request = {
           query: 'San Francisco',
           fields: ['photos', 'formatted_address', 'name', 'rating', 'opening_hours', 'geometry']
       };

       placesService.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
           if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
               console.log(results[0].formatted_address) // San Francisco, CA, USA
           }
           else {
               console.log("doesn't work");
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. Autocomplete in address form (full example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)) + country restriction

   ```
   function initAutocomplete() {
     // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
     // geographical location types.
     autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
         document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}});

     // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
     // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
     autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

     // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
     // address fields in the form.
     autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
   }

   function fillInAddress() {
     // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

     for (var component in componentForm) {
       document.getElementById(component).value = '';
       document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
     }

     // Get each component of the address from the place details,
     // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
     for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
       var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
       if (componentForm[addressType]) {
         var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
         document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Find Place web service (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests))

   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=San%20Francisco&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=YOUR_API_KEY
4. Autocomplete web service (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)) + country restriction

   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=San+Francisco&types=geocode&components=country:us&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Hope this clarifies your question!

Comment: In that case you can actually just use a div, or implement Autocomplete in a form, or use the web service etc. There are many mapless options (with proper attributions given). Please clarify your use case and I will modify my answer accordingly.